# Jquery - techniques for extending 'perimeter' for mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to implement behaviour such that a mouseover/hover event is triggered when the mouse pointer hovers over a certain div, but such that the mouseout event tiggers not when the pointer leaves the div, but when it leaves the area 10px ourside the div.

Is there any way of achieving this that doesn't involve creating a larger  parent div to bind the mouseout event to?

Comment: So the mouseout and mouseover don't have the same area?

Comment: Sound like you would have to implement your own version of hover to do this by tracking the mouse position and checking it relative to the div.

Comment: I don't know if there is a direct way to do this, but maybe create a wrapper div on the mouseover event and delete it on mouseout. jquery has a .wrap/.unwrap function. Then obviously the wrapper div would have a padding or whatever. You can create a delegate event on the wrapper div for the mouseout event, it should fire that way.

Comment: @Matt - interesting, hadn't though of that.

Answer (score 5):

My comment got me interested to see if it was possible and it's actually quite easy. No idea how well it would run in different browsers and with lots of divs but it works in this example:

http://jsbin.com/exulef/2/edit

```
var hello = $('#hello');
var position = hello.offset();
var height = hello.height();
var width = hello.width();

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (hello.data('inside')) {
    if ((e.pageX < position.left - 10 || e.pageX > position.left + width + 10) || 
       (e.pageY < position.top - 10 || e.pageY > position.top + height + 10)) {
      hello.text(position.top + " : " + position.left + " : " + e.pageX + " : " + e.pageY + "  Outside")
        .data('inside', false);
    }
  }
  else {
    if ((e.pageX > position.left && e.pageX < position.left + width) && 
        (e.pageY > position.top && e.pageY < position.top + height)) {
      hello.text(position.top + " : " + position.left + " : " + e.pageX + " : " + e.pageY + "  Inside")
        .data('inside', true);
    }
  }  
});
```

hello is just a square div. Would be quite easy to turn into a plugin as well which I might do later, lol.

Edit - I did make this into a plugin in the end: http://jmonkee.net/wordpress/2011/09/07/jquery-extended-hover-plugin/

Comment: good plugin, trying to use it and wondering how do you pass in the parameter for `mouseOutExtend` to 100 pixels outside the radius?

Comment: @Chamilyan You pass it as the 3rd parameter to the plugin: `$('#hover').hoverExtend(mouseOverFunction, mouseOutFunction, { mouseOutExtend: 100 });` - http://jsfiddle.net/qeRQv/2/

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that without an external div, but it imply that your div will have a margin even when not hovered.

It uses the fact that the padding is inside the div, and the margin is outside.

- When nothing happens, we have a margin, we have to go inside the div to hover.
- When it's hovered, the margin becomes padding, this way we're inside the div for a little bit more when the mouse leaves the div.
- When we're leaving the padding, it's back to margin.

The css is something like:

```
.a{
   margin:10px;
}
div.b{
   padding:10px;
   margin:0;
}
```

Note that it's important to have a b selector that's a bit more specific in order to have it apply without using important and without taking attention of the order.

The js would be:

```
$(".a").bind("mouseenter",function(){
    $(this).addClass("b");
}).bind("mouseleave",function(){
    $(this).removeClass("b");
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ynecV/

Comment: The second selector is already "a bit more specific", because it's behind the first selector. No need to "artificially" make it more specific.

Comment: I know that order matters, but I (and I know it's a matter of taste) find it better to artificially specify rather than relying on the order.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would go with wrapping desired div in another one and binding mouseout on it - it would be most reliable solution.

BUT, if you insist on not creating another div, then I would bind custom mousemove handler that would be binded (on document) on mouseenter over div, and would detect the fact that mouse move away from div bounding box for more than 10px. If so, mousemove handler would fire custom jQuery event and then it would unbind itself.